# Bash Scripting Ignore blank lines + comments in a passed through file

Tags: bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

##############################################################
# ASSIGNMENT DUE NOV m19/t20
# Allow for blank lines in the file
# Allow for comments in the file that start tih '#'
# Validate ssn with regex
# Log SIG, line numbers, filename, and bad ssn
# Validat domain with regex (lowercase and digits)
# Log SIG, line number, filename, and bad ip
# add domain name and ip to /etc/hosts only when required
# (Always use fullly qualified paths in bash scripts)
# regex files should be in /root/scripts/regex/
##############################################################

# Script to check for errors and then print to screen
args_expected=1
if [ ${#} -ne ${args_expected} ]
then
    echo "Usage error: expected ${args_expected}, got ${#}"
    echo "Exiting"
    exit
fi

IFS_save=$IFS
IFS=','

user_cnt=0

#Script to make usernames for the users in the file
while read lastname firstname midname ssn domain ip;
do
    username=${firstname:0:1}${midname:0:1}${lastname}
    echo "user_cnt=${user_cnt} username: $username"

    echo $lastname $firstname $midname $ssn $domain $ip;
    let ++user_cnt

    #Allows blank line within files
    if [ "${lastname}" = " " ]
    then
        #needs to skip over the blank line and not to count it as a user
    else
        continue
    fi
done < ${1}

IFS=$IFS_save
```

1. This program has a lot left to it that needs to be done but right now I need help with the comments and blank lines.
2. Whenever I use this program through the sample file I have it keeps adding blank lines as users.
3. I have tried using grep -o awk -F and sed regex options in removing / ignoring blank lines but in the form I have the if statement all it does is read the blank lines and adds them to the user count.

Comment: Please edit your Q to include a small set of sample input and your expected output from that same input. Good luck.

Comment: `expected ${args_expected}, got ${#}` is an error message.  Error messages belong on stderr.  And if your script fails, it should return non zero. `echo "error message" >&2; exit 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the check for a blank username or comment *before* you increment `user_cnt`. And use `continue` in that case, not the case where it's not blank.

And `" "` is not an empty username, it's a username containing a space character. The empty string is `""`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

##############################################################
# ASSIGNMENT DUE NOV m19/t20
# Allow for blank lines in the file
# Allow for comments in the file that start tih '#'
# Validate ssn with regex
# Log SIG, line numbers, filename, and bad ssn
# Validat domain with regex (lowercase and digits)
# Log SIG, line number, filename, and bad ip
# add domain name and ip to /etc/hosts only when required
# (Always use fullly qualified paths in bash scripts)
# regex files should be in /root/scripts/regex/
##############################################################

# Script to check for errors and then print to screen
args_expected=1
if [ ${#} -ne ${args_expected} ]
then
    echo "Usage error: expected ${args_expected}, got ${#}"
    echo "Exiting"
    exit
fi

IFS_save=$IFS
IFS=','

user_cnt=0

#Script to make usernames for the users in the file
while read lastname firstname midname ssn domain ip;
do
    # Check for blank or comment
    if [[ $lastname = "" || $lastname = "#"* ]]
    then
        continue
    fi

    username=${firstname:0:1}${midname:0:1}${lastname}
    echo "user_cnt=${user_cnt} username: $username"

    echo $lastname $firstname $midname $ssn $domain $ip;
    let ++user_cnt
done < ${1}

IFS=$IFS_save
```

I tested with the following CSV file:

```
margolin,barry,w,104500034,margolin.com,1.2.3.4

#foobar
jones,james,e,123455667,foobar.com,1.1.1.1
```

and the output was:

```
user_cnt=0 username: bwmargolin
margolin barry w 104500034 margolin.com 1.2.3.4
user_cnt=1 username: jejones
jones james e 123455667 foobar.com 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: oh nvm I forgot to move the whole if statement above, thanks m8